# pass value to servlet from a hidden input type

Tags: html, servlets

I am trying to pass the parameter called `value` in the hidden input type to my servlet.
It is like that:

```
retour.append("<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"id_" + nomTab + "_" + compteur + "\"  value=\"" + object.getIdDailyTimeSheet() + "\"/>");
retour.append("<button id=edit name=edit type=submit onClick= editarow()>");
retour.append("<img src=edit.gif />");
retour.append("</button>");
retour.append("</td>");
```

But the method get parameter recommend a name to be able to get the value here.
So how can I deal with it? Here I want to pass to the servlet the value of `object.getIdDailyTimeSheet()`.

Comment: Generating HTML in servlet code is considered bad practice. Use JSP for template text.

Comment: I know that servlet is provided to do java code but i am dealing with java code generating html to create some dynamic treatements in jsp that only html could not genertated. 
any way thanks  it will be helpfull certainly;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a "Name" attribute to your Hidden field as:

```
retour.append(".. name=[field_name] ..");
```